# StrictMode with penaltyLog does not show useful stack trace

Tags: java, android

I was getting a 'A resource failed to call close' message in my logcat.  So I turned on some StrictMode things in my Application.onCreate method.

```
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder(StrictMode.getVmPolicy())
            .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDeath()
            .build());
```

Now I get this unhelpful stack trace in my logcat:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. Callsite: close
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1992)
    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:338)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixSecureDirectoryStream.finalize(UnixSecureDirectoryStream.java:580)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:339)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.processReference(Daemons.java:324)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:300)
    at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

What is going on?  What am I mishandling?  Where is it happening?  Where do I go from here?

Comment: This SO might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444092/how-to-debug-leak-caused-by-unixdirectorystream-in-android-app